# how to check-box from a list using firebase data on ionic4

Tags: typescript, ionic4

i want to create a check-box list using fireBase data on my ionic4 project but it seems that it doesn't work

that's my html page :

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let etudiant of etudiants | async">
      <ion-label>{{etudiant.nom}}</ion-label>
      <ion-checkbox slot="end" color= "danger" [(ngModel)]="etudiant.isChecked"></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

that's my ts page :

```
export class AbsencePage implements OnInit {

  etudiant : Observable<any[]>;

  constructor( private db: AngularFirestore, 
                private menu: MenuController, 
                private alertC: AlertController, 
                private route: Router, 
                private modal: ModalController ) 
  {
    this.etudiant = db.collection('Étudiants').valueChanges();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Comment: The only worse explanation than `doesn't work` is no explanation at all. And two way binding wouldn't work here anyways - `[(ngModel)]`, I mean it wont' update data in FIrebase, if you are not aware of this